# Does adding 1 drive to an mdadm RAID5 with SSDs require writing all disks once?

Tags: raid, mdadm, ssd, raid5

I’m going to build a new storage with a few SSDs in RAID5 under Linux’ mdadm. I am considering buying 5 or 6 SSDs now.

If I add another SSD in the future does adding it to the RAID5 require a full write on all then used SSDs? SSDs have a limited write capability and it would be a small indicator for me to buy more free space now. I am not sure whether data must be rearranged in order to grow the array.

Comment: I would not worry about a single complete rewrite. A good quality SSD is good for 60-150 TB according to one [estimate](https://www.ontrack.com/en-us/blog/how-long-do-ssds-really-last). Another [says](https://datarecovery.com/rd/ssd-write-cycles/) 560TB, equivalent to 560 complete rewrites on a 1TB disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to expand the array so to increase its capacity, then yes, this addition will be followed by the *reshape* operation and it will require a complete rewrite of all component devices, including the new one.

However, a single full rewrite a few times should not concern you much. You're not going to reshape an array every day and even every month, aren't you?

Also, notice that at least *one* full write is inevitable anyway since it is required when you create a RAID5 array.